# Implement EPR Imaging deconvolution

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing, imaging, epr-experiment

I have bruker's EPRI data and I want to deconvolute it.

I read some article, that says
$$
f(r) = x(r) \circledast g(r) \\
F(ω) = X(ω) \times G(ω) \\
X(ω) = \frac{F(ω)}{G(ω)}
$$
$f(r)$: imaging spectre, $x(r)$: spin density, $g(r)$: non-gradient spectre

$\circledast$: convolution, capital letter means Fourier translated. $r$ means spatial coordinate.

I have non-gradient spectre and Imaging spectre but these are the spectra of the magnetic field strength not of spatial coordinate.

How do I convert $f(B)$ to $f(r)$? Or is it ok to use $f(B)$ as $f(r)$?

Reference: Y. Deng, G. He, P. Kuppusamy, J. L. Zweier, "Deconvolution algorithm based on automatic cutoff frequency selection for EPR imaging", [*Magn. Reson. Med.* **50**, 444-448 (2003)](https://doi.org/10.1002/mrm.10533).

Answer (score 0):

If you know how the B fields changes with position $r$, you could calculate the function $f(r)$. However, as you suggested, by Fourier transforming the function $f(B)$, you will obtain $F(\omega_B)$, where $\omega_B$ is the "magnetic (angular) frequency". The Fourier convolution theorem still holds. So the only difference is that your result uses "magnetic (angular) frequencies" $\omega_B$ instead of "spatial (angular) frequencies" $\omega_r$.